# How to reduced the particular row height in React table/react checkbox table

Tags: reactjs

I am using React table with checkbox property and wanted to reduced the default react table row height, so that 20 row can fit in table.

Piece of code:

Column defined structure:

```
function getColumns() {
  const columns = [
    { Header: "From", accessor: "senderID" },
    { Header: "To", accessor: "receiverID" },
    { Header: "Transaction File", accessor: "fileName" },
    { Header: "Transaction Date", accessor: "transationDate" },
    { Header: "Record Count", accessor: "recordCount" },
    { Header: "Status", accessor: "status" }
  ];
  return columns;
}
```

My table looks like below.Instead of 5 to 6 rows wanted to set 20 rows on same layout:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried customizing the height [like this example in the documenation](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#custom-cell-header-and-footer-rendering)?

Comment: tried but row height is still same.

Comment: Could you please provide the exact piece of code.

Comment: looks lIke you have to add props ```showPageSizeOptions: true,``` 
```<ReactTable
    showPageSizeOptions={true}
    columns={this.getColumns()}
  />```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding styles inside getTdProps props of the ReactTable component.

```
<ReactTable
         columns={cData}
         data={data}
         getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => ({
              style: {
                height: '20px',
              },
          })}
          minRows={20}
  />
```